# Sum of products simplification, boolean algebra

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra, parity

is there a way to simplify this sum of products?

(¬a∧¬b∧c∧d)∨(¬a∧b∧¬c∧d)∨(¬a∧b∧c∧¬d)∨(a∧¬b∧¬c∧d)∨(a∧¬b∧c∧¬d)∨(a∧b∧¬c∧¬d)∨(a∧b∧c∧d)

I tried factoring out c and d from the first and last term, but after that I just get stuck. Any help/links would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. It's already a minimum sum of products.

If we're allowed to use the XOR operator (denoted by $\oplus$), then we could rewrite it as:
$$
\neg((a \oplus b \oplus c \oplus d) \lor (\neg a \land \neg b \land \neg c \land \neg d ))
$$